# Getting Xpath from plain text

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Im trying to get xpath from text instead of a URL.  But i keep getting the error "AttributeError: 'HtmlElement' object has no attribute 'XPath'"

see code below.

```
from lxml import html

var ='''<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Selecting content on a web page with XPath</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     This is the body
  </body>
</html>
'''

tree = html.fromstring(var)

body = tree.XPath('//*/body')

print(body)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been 15 years since I last used Python, but as far as I can tell, it is a case-sensitive language, and the [`xpath`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#xpath) method is all lowercase.

So try this:

```
body = tree.xpath('//*/body')
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was it :)